# Create instance of model w/ Paperclip attachment from Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to create a user from the rails console and this isn't working

```
User.new({:email => "guy@gmail.com",  :password => "pass", :name => "guy"}).save(false)
```

I keep getting:

```
AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey: You did not provide both required access keys. Please provide the access_key_id and the secret_access_key.
```

I'm using paperclip to store user photos but I can't figure this out, it works fine when I create a user from the normal form. I don't require a photo upon registration either.

Comment: Accept more questions. Get more answers. Be a good S.O. citizen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Paperclip/AWS is getting configured when you are running the Rails console, not just when booting your app with another server. This has nothing to do with Authlogic, as you can verify by commenting out all of the Authlogic functionality from your model and testing again.